# SharePoint add-in won't create subsites upon button click

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sub-site, aspx

I have recently created a add-in for SharePoint online that will allow me to make a subsite. My written code doesn't show any errors, but it seems like it won't execute after a button click.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        bindButtonClick();
    });

    function bindButtonClick() {
        $("Submit").on("click", function () {
            var name = $("Naam").val(); // var name = Titel van de subsite
            var description = $("Omschrijving").val(); // var description = Omschrijving van de subsite
            if (name == '' || description == '') {
                alert("Vul eerst alle velden in.");
            }
            else {
                createSite();
            }
        });
    }

    function createSite() {
        // Eerst de variabelen opzetten
        var siteTitle = $("Naam").val(); 
        var siteDesc = $("Omschrijving").val(); 
        var siteUrl = $("URLInput").val();

        //  Omgevingsinfo opslaan in variabelen
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('https://orgname.sharepoint.com/sites/addin-development');
        var collWeb = clientContext.get_web().get_webs();
        var webCreationInfo = new SP.WebCreationInformation();

        // webCreationInfo invoeren
        webCreationInfo.set_title(siteTitle);
        webCreationInfo.set_description(siteDesc);
        webCreationInfo.set_language(1043); // id=1043 voor nederlands, id=1033 voor engels. Meer id's hier:https://goo.gl/2YCAyo
        webCreationInfo.set_url(siteUrl);
        webCreationInfo.set_useSamePermissionsAsParentSite(true);
        webCreationInfo.set_webTemplate("STS#0");

        // webCreationInfo opslaan en site-aanmaakquery uitvoeren
        var oNewWebsite = collWeb.add(webCreationInfo);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.CreateDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
        );
    }

    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        alert("De site is met succes aangemaakt!");
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed.' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
</script>
```

```
<div>
    <p id="message">
        <!-- The following content will be replaced with the user name when you run the app - see App.js -->
        initializing...
    </p>
</div>

<asp:Label ID="Naam" runat="server" Text="Label">Voer hier de naam van de site in</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="NaamInput" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <!-- site title -->

<asp:Label ID="URL" runat="server" Text="Label">Voer hier de naam(url) van de site in</asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="URLDescr" runat="server" Text="Label">https://orgname.sharepoint.com/sites/addin-development/</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="URLInput" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <!-- site url -->

<asp:Label ID="Projector" runat="server" Text="Label">Voer hier de naam van de projector in</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="ProjectorInput" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Label ID="KlantNaam" runat="server" Text="Label">Voer hier de naam van de klant in</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="KlantNaamInput" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Label ID="Omschrijving" runat="server" Text="Label">Voer hier de omschrijving van de site in</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="OmschrijvingInput" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <!-- site description -->

<asp:Label ID="Logo" runat="server" Text="Label">Upload hier het logo van de site</asp:Label>
<asp:FileUpload ID="LogoInput" runat="server" /> <!-- site logo -->

<asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Creëer subsite" value="Submit"/>
```

As soon as i click the button, the page refreshes and the input stays in the textboxes, but nothing happens. The site doesn't get created. This code is part of a SharePoint hosted add-in and i placed it in the page default.aspx. I tried putting the javascript in the App.js but that didn't work either.

I'd appreciate if anyone could tell me what's going wrong here, Thanks!